# Determine from which parent class an attribute is coming from

Tags: python

To give some backstory, I am working in a fairly large codebase which may or may not have had some questionable architectural decisions made in its creation, so often times I need to figure out from which of the parent classes an attribute or function is coming from.

This code will do it, but it seems like there is probably a more pythonic way to do this:

```
def find_attribute_class(model, attribute):
    return [m for m in model.mro() if attribute in m.__dict__]
```

Example:

```
class Bar(object):
    junk = {}

class Foo(Bar):
    trunk = []

find_attribute_class(Foo, 'junk') # returns [Bar]
find_attribute_class(Foo, 'trunk') # returns [Foo]
```

Comment: What's the *problem* with what you have?

Comment: Nothing really, it just seems like there should be a builtin function for this, rather than having to roll my own.

Comment: You can look into `inspect`, but frankly it'd be easiest to get a decent IDE that lets you easily move around the class hierarchy.

Comment: i'll check out inspect.  I don't think an IDE is the solution (currently using sublime) because that involves looking, and I want python to tell me where it is :)

Comment: Are you usually looking for the class containing a class variable (like in your examples) or for methods? In recent versions of Python, you can use `__qualname__` to get at a qualified name of a method (including the class). Starting in Python 3.5, bound methods will use `__qualname__` in their `repr` as well, so if your `o` object has a `foo` method, `print(o.foo)` will tell you where `foo` was defined (older versions didn't do this properly however, see [this bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue21389)).